# Dependant widgets in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a small GUI app in Python that uses Tk. It has several filters --- a text entries (they set filter values) with checkboxes (which set filter on/off). I create filters as a class inhetrited from `ttk`'s `Labelframe`:

```
from tkinter.ttk import Labelframe
import tkinter as tk 

class FilterWidget(Labelframe):

    def __init__(self, parent, label):
        Labelframe.__init__(self, parent, text=label)
        self.grid()
        self._entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self._entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self._checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(self, command=lambda: print(self))
        self._checkbox.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Then I create several instances of this class and place them in GUI:

```
root = tk.Tk()

source_filter = FilterWidget(root, "Source")
source_filter.grid(row=0, column=0)
level_filter = FilterWidget(root, "Severity")
level_filter.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

The widgets are created and correctly displayed. However, when one of the checkboxes is clicked and changes state, the other changes state as well!

When diffrent checkboxes are clicked, `print` command outputs `.!filterwidget` and `.!filterwidget2`, so those are separate objects.  It seems that they are somehow implicitly syncronized, but I have no idea how did this happend.

So, the question is: how to remove this dependancy and make checkboxes independant of each other?

Comment: I do not get the behavior you describe. Are you certain that this exact code exhibits the problem?

Comment: Yes, two snippets in the answer are the complete code that reproduces the problem for me. I'm running Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]) on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm) mention,

> To use a Checkbutton, you must create a Tkinter variable. To inspect
>   the button state, query the variable.

Here's your code updated to use an IntVar to store the Checkbutton state.

```
from tkinter.ttk import Labelframe
import tkinter as tk 

class FilterWidget(Labelframe):
    def __init__(self, parent, label):
        Labelframe.__init__(self, parent, text=label)
        self._entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self._entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self._var = tk.IntVar()
        callback = lambda: print(self._entry.get(), self._var.get())
        checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(self, variable=self._var, command=callback)
        checkbox.grid(row=0, column=1)

root = tk.Tk()

source_filter = FilterWidget(root, "Source")
source_filter.grid(row=0, column=0)
level_filter = FilterWidget(root, "Severity")
level_filter.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, that fixes the problem. I never inended to use the checkbox value explicitly and only relied on a callback, so I thought that creating one is not necessary. More fool me for not paying enough attention to the docs.

Comment: @Month Never underestimate Tkinter's ability to bewilder you with its various quirks. ;)